# React Native: Link Two Projects

Tags: react-native, storybook

I am just starting out with React Native for a new app.

I have broken down the project into components. I have used Storybook to create these components (a reat-native project).

I want to maintain this components project as a separate repo that can be used with my main project as well as other projects.

When I create my main project how, do I import the components that I have already been created in the from the 'components project' into my main project?
Is there a way to link the two react native apps?